# Right way to make a bash script run as a service

Tags: bash, service, systemctl

I have a simple script which monitors my notebook's battery level. Is anything wrong with how I set up my ***.service** file since I keep getting `(code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)` errors.

**batterylevel-warning.sh**

Permissions set to 777.

```
#!/bin/bash

CRITICAL_PERCENTAGE=`cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/capacity`
STATUS=`cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/status`
ICON="/usr/share/icons/Paper/512x512/status/battery-low.png"

if [ $STATUS == "Discharging" ]; then
    if [ $CRITICAL_PERCENTAGE -eq 20 ]; then
        notify-send -u critical -t 2000 -i $ICON "You need to charge your battery now!!! It is at $CRITICAL_PERCENTAGE%!!!"
    fi
fi
```

**batterylevel.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=Send alerts on low battery starting at 25%.

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/myhome/.scripts/batterylevel-warning.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Implement

```
# Create sym link
sudo ln-s /home/myhome/.scripts/batterylevel.service /etc/systemd/system
# Enable and start
sudo systemctl enable batterylevel.service
sudo systemctl start batterylevel.service
```

**Problem:** When my battery hits 25% I run `sudo systemctl status batterylevel.service` and get:

```
● batterylevel.service - Send alerts on low battery starting at 25%. Designed for silverlance.
   Loaded: loaded (/home/myhome/.scripts/batterylevel.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2020-03-02 23:04:02 PST; 4s ago
  Process: 5357 ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/myhome/.scripts/batterylevel-warning.sh (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 5357 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

I also ran `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` somewhere in there but still no success. Sorry for the long post.

Comment: Does your script work when run manually instead of a service?

Comment: I would advise against relying on this test: `[ $CRITICAL_PERCENTAGE -eq 20 ]`. If your battery level drops from 21% to 19% without hitting the 20% mark then you won’t get the notification, even though you probably want to. You should work around something like `[ $CRITICAL_PERCENTAGE -le 20 ]` (`-le` instead of `eq`).

Comment: Does `journalctl -l` give an error message from your script? I suspect it will show the `notify-send` command failing and that that's were the error value is coming from

Comment: @vdavid Yes, it works fine when I run it via `./batterylevel-warning.sh`. I'll try out what you said regarding the use of `-le`. @Jon I better check.

Answer (score 0):

So there are two problems here.

The first problem is that `systemd` expects `simple` services to run forever. Currently your script will just run once when you run `systemctl start` and then terminate. That's fine and several services work that way, but I don't think it is what you intended. Try recoding your script to poll:

```sh
while true; do
    if [ $STATUS == "Discharging" ]; then
        if [ $CRITICAL_PERCENTAGE -eq 20 ]; then
            notify-send -u critical -t 2000 -i $ICON "You need to charge your battery now!!! It is at $CRITICAL_PERCENTAGE%!!!"
        fi
    fi
    sleep 60
done
```

The second problem is that something in your script is returning an error code. The obvious candidate is the `notify-send` command. `notify-send` is unlikely to be able to contact your desktop manager from `systemd`, so that's almost certainly the problem. The following Stack Exchange article describes a similar problem someone had getting `notify-send` to run under `cron`. You'll need to do something similar to get it running under `systemd`. That said, getting `systemd` to talk directly to a desktop manager is always going to be tricky, so it may be better use a different approach. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111188/using-notify-send-with-cron